# Input/output errors when running some programs in Lubuntu started from a bootable flash drive

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb, io

I downloaded Lubuntu 18.04 iso file into my flash drive and make the flash drive into a bootable device.

I inserted the flash drive into a laptop (C55t-A) and booted into Lubuntu without actually installing it.

Now I find some programs can run well, but some programs don't.

For example, when I click Firefox from the desktop's panel's menu, it says:

> Failed to execute child process "firefox" (input/output error)

In terminal emulator,

```
$ evince some.pdf
bash: /usr/bin/evince: Input/output error

$ man ls
bash: /usr/bin/man: Input/output error
```

I was wondering how to solve the above problems?

Thanks.

Comment: An Input/Output error is usually hardware-related Bad News. Consider the possibility that your flash drive has reached it's end of life.

Comment: Strange. After I reboot into the live flash drive, the IO error is gone. Wonder why